# The following C statement while debugging shows the value of k as -2. Why? Actually, It should show -2.000000

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j = -5;
    float k = j / 2;
    printf("%d\n", j % 2);
    printf("%1.1f\n", k);
}
```

The above code while debugging shows the value of `k` as `-2`. Why? Actually, It should show `-2.000000`.

Comment: What are you using to debug this code?

Comment: I am using gdb for debugging.

Answer (score 5):

`-2` and `-2.000000` are the same value.  It's just a matter of how many digits of precision are printed.

If you leave out the precision specifier when you print `k`, it will use the default of 6:

```
printf("%f\n", k);
```

Output:

```
-2.000000
```

As for gdb, it will only show the required number of significant digits when printing a `float`.  Because the value -2 can be represented exactly, it doesn't show any additional digits.